# How do I install usb using npm

Tags: usb, node.js, nodered

I'm trying to install a npm [usb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb) package on a raspberry pi. It's needed by a library (in turn used by a node for node-red) but trying to install that seperately didn't work, so I'm installing this dependency first, by doing the following in the desired directory:

```
sudo npm install usb
```

It seems to run fine though I do get the following stacktrace:

```
> usb@1.2.0 install /home/pi/Documents/Nodes/mynode/node_modules/usb
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://github.com/tessel/node-usb/releases/download/1.2.0/usb_bindings-v1.2.0-node-v48-linux-arm.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for usb@1.2.0 and node@6.11.2 (node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/6.11.2"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/home/pi/Documents/Nodes/ant_plus_node/node_modules/usb/.node-gyp"
make ✖ ERR  Missing Makefile / Bakefile
make ℹ info Run "make init" to generate a Makefile.
ant_plus_node@0.2.1 /home/pi/Documents/Nodes/ant_plus_node
└─┬ ant-plus@0.0.9
  └── usb@1.2.0
```

The `Missing Makfile / Bakefile` seemed especially weird to me. When I attempt to use the node in node-red I get the following message:

```
"Error: /home/pi/Documents/Nodes/ant_plus_node/node_modules/usb/src/binding/usb_bindings.node: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

And yes, when I go to the directory it's not there. So I tried going to the the usb module and running `make init` and running the install again. But still no `usb_bindings.node` to be found.

Can anyone point me to a possible direction where this might be going wrong? Perhaps something with `node-pre-gyp`? I don't need an "as-is" answer perse.

As a sidenote, when I'm in the package I'm trying to link using 'npm link', which uses a library I partially wrote which has 'usb' as a dependency, I get the exact same stacktrace.

I have:
nodejs version 6.11.12
npm version 3.10.10
And in case relevant (I've seen them being mentioned in the `node-pre-gyp` documentation):
python version 2.7.9
python3 version 3.4.2

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message suggests doing make init?

Comment: I have actually, but the problem persists. I'll update the question however.

Comment: What bothers me as well is that the stack trace is identicaly, even after doing make init.